# VSCode debug - how to show full list contents

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When debugging Python in VSCode, does anyone know how to get it to show the full list contents instead of collapsing it?

There's probably a setting for this, but I can't find it. It's a pain having to remember to wrap everything you want to see in a `str()` call.

[image]

I have the same problem in both the Debug Console and Variables panel.

Before anyone suggests clicking the `>` to expand the values, that isn't always helpful either.

[image]

EDIT:

Minimum reproducible example (as shown in the image above). In the Debug Console, type

```
mycoordinates=[[(0.0,0.0),(1.0,1.0)]]
```

Then try and show that variable

```
mycoordinates
```

VSCode shows the list in the collapsed form. If you want to see the actual values, you need to do this

```
str(mycoordinates)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
and describe the steps in detail and what effect you expect?